# How do I delete targets on Xcode version 13.0

Tags: xcode

I am a beginner starting C on Xcode. I tried to use multiple C files on one project and figured out making another target can solve the problem. Now, I want to delete the new target that I made but, when I hit the delete button it just shuts down itself. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRsET.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Target and select Delete.

Comment: I did several times, but it shuts down itself.

Comment: You hit the delete button. Can you click on the right click menu and select delete ?

Comment: Yeah I did exactly what you said several times lol. Should I delete Xcode and install it again.

Comment: Try delete the C Practice target. If that does not work click on Scheme->Manage Schemes, and click the `-` at the bottom to delete the entire scheme